# How do i know if my application is running in weblogic in debug mode?

Tags: java, debugging, weblogic

Say that i want my application to behave differently when running in debug mode in WebLogic - is there a flag that i can check?

ie:

```
if (weblogic.DEBUG) Console.writeline("running in debug mode in weblogic");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add arguments to your weblogic server to allow you to debug it remotely, specifically by setting the `-Xdebug` option in your `startWebLogic` script.

You can see a full example in the Oracle docs [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/remotedebugwls-086628.html)

And in a similar question here: [How to debug Java EE application using WebLogic 10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042858/how-to-debug-java-ee-application-using-weblogic-10-3)

Once you have debug turned on you could pull it out of the JVM args/system properties like shown here: [How to get vm arguments from inside of java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490869/how-to-get-vm-arguments-from-inside-of-java-application)

If you're not asking about debug but instead asking how to tell if your server is in production mode vs development mode, you can also access `isProductionModeEnabled()` via JMX, as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/javadocs_mhome/weblogic/management/configuration/DomainMBean.html#isProductionModeEnabled())

You can also edit the logging levels for your servers to turn debug on...

Comment: unfortunately, the linked answers don't mention how one might find an argument passed in with the -X option (-Xdebug doesn't seem to be available through System.getProperty())

Comment: You can certainly add your own additional property value to the `startWebLogic` script itself to go along with the options like -Xdebug so you can pull out `System.getProperty('myCustomDebugOption')`.

Comment: that's too heavyweight. i'd rather just find out if weblogic is running in debug mode, without messing with any of the scripts etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DomainRuntimeServiceMBean and ServerRuntimeMBean provided by weblogic. There is an example on the oracle website of invoking these 2 MBeans to get the status of the server. I've pasted it below. [Source can be found here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/wlsmbeanref/core/index.html)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.management.MBeanServerConnection;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnector;
import javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory;
import javax.management.remote.JMXServiceURL;
import javax.naming.Context;
public class PrintServerState {
   private static MBeanServerConnection connection;
   private static JMXConnector connector;
   private static final ObjectName service;
   // Initializing the object name for DomainRuntimeServiceMBean
   // so it can be used throughout the class.
   static {
      try {
         service = new ObjectName(
            "com.bea:Name=DomainRuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.
             mbeanservers.domainruntime.DomainRuntimeServiceMBean");
      }catch (MalformedObjectNameException e) {
         throw new AssertionError(e.getMessage());
      }
   }
   /*
   * Initialize connection to the Domain Runtime MBean Server
   */
   public static void initConnection(String hostname, String portString, 
      String username, String password) throws IOException,
      MalformedURLException { 
      String protocol = "t3";
      Integer portInteger = Integer.valueOf(portString);
      int port = portInteger.intValue();
      String jndiroot = "/jndi/";
      String mserver = "weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime";
      JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL(protocol, hostname,
         port, jndiroot + mserver);
      Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
      h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
      h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
      h.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES,
         "weblogic.management.remote");
      connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h);
      connection = connector.getMBeanServerConnection();
   }
   /* 
   * Print an array of ServerRuntimeMBeans.
   * This MBean is the root of the runtime MBean hierarchy, and
   * each server in the domain hosts its own instance.
   */
   public static ObjectName[] getServerRuntimes() throws Exception {
      return (ObjectName[]) connection.getAttribute(service,
         "ServerRuntimes");
   }
   /* 
   * Iterate through ServerRuntimeMBeans and get the name and state
   */
   public void printNameAndState() throws Exception {
      ObjectName[] serverRT = getServerRuntimes();
      System.out.println("got server runtimes");
      int length = (int) serverRT.length;
      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
         String name = (String) connection.getAttribute(serverRT[i],
            "Name");
         String state = (String) connection.getAttribute(serverRT[i],
            "State");
         System.out.println("Server name: " + name + ".   Server state: "
            + state);
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String hostname = args[0];
      String portString = args[1];
      String username = args[2];
      String password = args[3];
      PrintServerState s = new PrintServerState();
      initConnection(hostname, portString, username, password);
      s.printNameAndState();
      connector.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the entire code was necessary since the gist is ` String state = (String) connection.getAttribute(serverRT[i],
            "State");` Answers should be to the point without anyone having read lot of code.

Comment: The entire source is helpful since it is stand-alone and can be run for quick evaluation. Also, I couldn't actually get direct link to the file just the main MBean reference page

Comment: Ok I see - the purpose of your snippet was provide some code to dump the properties rather than explain them that they can use `getAttribute(mbean, 'State')` which was burried in it.

Answer (score -1):

You can the see debug socket log in the weblogic console like below,

Listening for transport dt_socket at address: xxxx

where xxxx is port number. By default the port number would be 8453